# Error when connecting to gke cluster from kubernetes-incubator/client-python

Tags: python, authentication, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to connect to my gke cluster using `kubernetes-incubator/client-python` library. I'm running just the basic query:

```
from kubernetes import client, config
# Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
config.load_kube_config()
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
for i in ret.items:
print("%s\t%s\t%s" % (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))
```

And I'm getting an error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
RefreshError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-40695f414daf> in <module>()
      2 
      3 # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper utility
----> 4 config.load_kube_config()
      5 
      6 v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/distpackages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in 
load_kube_config(config_file, context, client_configuration, 
persist_config)
    359         config_file, active_context=context,
    360         client_configuration=client_configuration,    
--> 361         config_persister=config_persister).load_and_set()
    362 
    363 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in load_and_set(self)
    251 
    252     def load_and_set(self):
--> 253         self._load_authentication()
    254         self._load_cluster_info()
    255         self._set_config()

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in 
    _load_authentication(self)
        174         if not self._user:
        175             return

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in _load_gcp_token(self)
    194                  _is_expired(provider['config']['expiry']))):
    195             # token is not available or expired, refresh it
--> 196             self._refresh_gcp_token()
    197 
    198         self.token = "Bearer %s" % provider['config']['access-token']

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in _refresh_gcp_token(self)
    203             self._user['auth-provider'].value['config'] = {}
    204         provider = self._user['auth-provider']['config']
--> 205         credentials = self._get_google_credentials()
    206         provider.value['access-token'] = credentials.token
    207         provider.value['expiry'] = format_rfc3339(credentials.expiry)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.pyc in _refresh_credentials()
    133             credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
    134             request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
--> 135             credentials.refresh(request)
    136             return credentials
    137 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.pyc in refresh(self, request)
    320         assertion = self._make_authorization_grant_assertion()
    321         access_token, expiry, _ = _client.jwt_grant(
--> 322             request, self._token_uri, assertion)
    323         self.token = access_token
    324         self.expiry = expiry

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.pyc in jwt_grant(request, token_uri, assertion)
    141     }
    142 
--> 143     response_data = _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
    144 
    145     try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.pyc in _token_endpoint_request(request, token_uri, body)
    107 
    108     if response.status != http_client.OK:
--> 109         _handle_error_response(response_body)
    110 
    111     response_data = json.loads(response_body)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.pyc in _handle_error_response(response_body)
     57 
     58     raise exceptions.RefreshError(
---> 59         error_details, response_body)
     60 
     61 

RefreshError: ('invalid_scope: Empty or missing scope not allowed.', u'{\n  "error" : "invalid_scope",\n  "error_description" : "Empty or missing scope not allowed."\n}')
```

I thought there was an issue with my kube.config file. So I removed it and created the cluster again in order to recreate a new kube.config file. The issue remained. Can you help me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with your Google Cloud Platform credentials. They're not being found and you're not able to interact with the service. [Here's some instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) on how to set those up. Either point the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to your credentials file or authenticate through the SDK.